# example 2 chapter 32 munkres

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

In the proof of $S_{\Omega} \times \bar S_{\Omega}$ is not normal in example 2 chapter 32 munkres' topology it claims that because the sequence ${\{x_1, \dots,} \} $ is countable then any of its upper bounds lies in $S_{\Omega}$. Why the least upper bound $b$ cannot be $\Omega $ itself? If I can prove that $b$ can never be $\Omega $ then the whole picture is complete!

PS Sorry the example is two pages not easy to retype, I thought because it is a common book available so maybe no need to include the whole example in here.

Comment: Basically it’s one part of the definition of $\Omega$ that it is **not** a supremum of any countable set of countable ordinals. Read up on the definition.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, the definition is given in lemma 10.2 which I don't know how to extract that $\Omega $ is not supremum..

Comment: It's just theorem 10.3 that is used here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theorem 10.3 in Munkres states explicitly:

> If $A$ is a countable subset of $S_\Omega$ then $A$ has an upper bound in $S_\Omega$.

So the lub of $A$, which is the *smallest* upper bound of $A$, must lie in $S_\Omega$ too (which is a section of $\Omega$ as stated before so contains with any ordinal also all smaller ordinals..

$\Omega$ itself is certainly *an* upperbound for $A$ in $\overline{S_\Omega}$, but certainly never the smallest one by the application of 10.3